# ScrollViewer jumps back to left border

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, zooming, scrollviewer

I have a ScrollViewer with an Image inside. Everytime i zoom the Image to be greater than my screen, it will bounce back to the left border. Strangely only left, not top, even if the image is larger than my screen, both width and height. `BringIntoViewOnFocusChange` does not seem to help.

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" >
            <Image ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: please show more XAML code. inside what control is ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13782921/3397793) answer solves the problem. If you don't want to disturb image size, you can use `ViewportHeight` and `ViewportWidth` properties of `ScrollViewer`

```
  <Image Width="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ViewportWidth}"
         Height="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ViewportHeight}"
         ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         Source="Assets/image.jpg" />
```